# Plotly charts in a for loop

Tags: r, knitr, plotly

I am converting ggplot2 charts using plotly and putting them in a knitr html output.
Here is a working copy of the report. 
http://rpubs.com/kausti/NSEFO-23-Mar-2016
The first chart is plotly chart and the following ones are not. I would like them to be plotly charts but I am stuck.

In the code below, plotChart function returns a ggplot2 plot. This code works!

```
for (tick in tradeOps$ticker)
{
  tmpDF = filter(tradeOps, ticker == tick)
  p = plotChart(tick = tick,Entry = tmpDF$Entry, Target =     tmpDF$Target, SL= tmpDF$SL, TradeType = tmpDF$TradeType, data = wd)
  p = p + annotate("text", x = as.Date(tmpDF$Date)+30, y =   tmpDF$Entry, label = tmpDF$Entry, colour = "blue")
  p = p + annotate("text", x = as.Date(tmpDF$Date)+30, y = tmpDF$Target, label = tmpDF$Target)
  p = p + annotate("text", x = as.Date(tmpDF$Date)+30, y = tmpDF$SL, label = tmpDF$SL)

  print(p)

}
```

Now if I change the last print statement to `print(ggplotly(p))` it just won't print the charts in html.
The code works outside knitr perfectly.

Also, `print(ggplotly(p))` works perfectly outside loops.
Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Including a reproducible example below. 
Following is my rmd file.

````
---
title: "tmp"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
s = NULL
a = data.frame(id = 1:15,x = 2:16, y = 15:1, z = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5),rep("c",5)))
for(i in unique(a$z)){
  s = a[a$z == i,]
  print(ggplot(s,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point())
}

```
````

This works perfectly with the output html showing three graphs.
Now, just changing the last print statement to 
`print(ggplotly(ggplot(s,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))` produces a blank html without any errors.

Running the same code in terminal works perfectly though

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
s = NULL
a = data.frame(id = 1:15,x = 2:16, y = 15:1, z = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5),rep("c",5)))
for(i in unique(a$z)){
  s = a[a$z == i,]
  print(ggplotly(ggplot(s,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Kaustubh

Comment: your post is not reproducible. Anyway you could add some data to your post?

Comment: @MLavoie I have edited the question to include a reproducible example. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out the problem is solved here
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273

knitr has known issues printing plotly charts in a loop.
Quoting the final answer cpsievert from here

````
```{r}
l <- htmltools::tagList()
for (i in 1:3) {
  l[[i]] <- as.widget(plot_ly(x = rnorm(10)))
}
l
```
````

This solved my problem. Though I ended up porting everything from ggplot2 to plotly R api before I found this solution.

MLavoie, thanks for your help. I had generated a dummy dataset just to create a reproducible example. Though your solution probably solves the dummy example, it is not all that relevant to me in the current problem. I think the solution provided here should be generic.

Thanks,
Kaustubh

Comment: Worked for me in 2022. Changed as.widget() to as_widget() after getting a warning about as.widget() being deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of alternatives for you. Let me know if it is helpful or not!

Suggestion1 (base `plotly` using `subplot`):

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
s = NULL
a = data.frame(id = 1:15,x = 2:16, y = 15:1, z = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5),rep("c",5)))
a$id2 <- as.integer(a$z)
p <- plot_ly(a, x = x, y = y, group=z, xaxis = paste0("x", id2), mode = "markers")
p <- subplot(p, nrows=3)
p

```
````

Suggestion2 (with `ggplot2` but using `facet`):

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
s = NULL
a = data.frame(id = 1:15,x = 2:16, y = 15:1, z = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5),rep("c",5)))
ggplotly(ggplot(a,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(z~.))

```
````