# ggVennDiagram in lagList in R MarkDown

Tags: r, r-markdown, venn-diagram, taglist, htmltools

I am trying to embed `Venn Diagrams` to my report made in `R MarkDown`. I have dinamic number of graphs so I generate them by `for loop`. I know that `R MarkDown` has "problem" with `loops` but I find the way how to solve it when I want to plot `plotly` objects.
But when I used a similar solution for `Ven Diagrams` from library `ggVennDiagram` I got error:

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") :    cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Code:

```
listToPlot <- list(
  x = unique(round(100*runif(100))),
  y = unique(round(100*runif(100))),
  z = unique(round(100*runif(100))),
  q = unique(round(100*runif(100)))
)

l <- htmltools::tagList()
if(length(listToPlot) > 3){
  for(i in c(2:length(listToPlot))){
    l[[i-1]] <- ggVennDiagram::ggVennDiagram(listToPlot[c(1,i)])
  }
}else{
  if(length(listToPlot) > 1){
    l[[1]] <- ggVennDiagram::ggVennDiagram(listToPlot)
  }
}
l
```

does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you based your code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371747/19959678). Using `htmltools::tagList()` seems to be a workaround for working with lists of plotly plots specifically. Since ggVennDiagram uses ggplot2, there is no need to use the plotly workaround as far as I can tell.

Replace this line:

```
l <- htmltools::tagList()
```

With this:

```
l <- list()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for help :) but how to display  a list of objects without showing those pesky [[indices]] in R Markdown?

Comment: I found `work(l, plot)`

Comment: Another possibility is `purrr::walk(l, print)`. The `walk()` function will iterate over each element of the list and pass it to the `print()` function separately, which ommits the printing of indices.